# Displaying Date from database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date-formatting

right now I'm storing a date in the database, in the format `date("Y-m-d")` and im storing it in [date column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

Now, I've retrieved it from the database but how can i display it like

```
October 31st 2010
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the date to a [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and format it using [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
echo date('F jS Y', strtotime($databaseDate));
```

The preferred way going forward should be the use of the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class though:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

$date = new DateTime($databaseDate);
echo $date->format('F jS Y');
```

Comment: Although this works perfectly, you might want to learn how to use the DateTime class of PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php.

Comment: @Itay Fair enough, added for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in your SQL query.

Example: `date_format(somefield, '%d-%m-%Y, %h:%i %p')`