# Change the desired output method of now() tags

Tags: php, mysql, date-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying Date from database PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066166/displaying-date-from-database-php)

I'm using this method in an insert.php function from a form for a small CMS/blog I'm making.
All i want to know is how to change the `now()` format.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Blog
(Date, Title, Message, Image) 
VALUES(now(), '$_POST[Title]' , '$_POST[Message]' , '$_POST[Image]' ) ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

I have a page that is using an echo

```
 echo "<h2>" . "Posted on:   " . $row['Date'] . "</h2>";
```

and this works fine, but its outputting it in a format I don't desire.
It's currently displayed as:

```
Posted on: 2012-11-03 16:17:29
```

Id prefer it to be something like

```
Posted on: 3rd November 2012 at 16:15
```

Is this easily done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MySQL function [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when you select the date out of your database.

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Date, 'Posted on: %D %M %Y at %H:%i') AS FormattedDate FROM `Blog`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%D %M %Y at %H:%i') FROM  Blog
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is easy:

```
   echo strftime('%e, %B, %Y', $row ['date']);

   Take a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
```