# Date is displaying wrong, but it's ok in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've researched a lot, but nothing helped me. I have 2 views: one for sign up and another one to edit your infos, if you forgot something.

Let's say I wrote in the date label the following month and year: 98/9889 (yeah, i'm retarded). It will shows correctly, but when I get my infos to edit it, it shows 31/1219, but in my database it's still 98/9889. Any idea?

**SIGN UP VIEW:**

```
<label for="antitetanica">Data da última dose antitetânica:</label>
<input type="text" id="antitetanica" name="antitetanica" value="echo date("m/Y", strtotime('antitetanica'))"/><br /><br>
```

**EDIT VIEW:**

```
<label for="antitetanica">Data da última dose antitetânica:</label>
<input type="input" name="antitetanica" id="antitetanica" value="<?php echo date("m/Y", strtotime('antitetanica')) ?>"/><br /><br>
```

Btw i was using DATE type in my database, but now i'm using varchar 255.

EDIT: now using the DATE type in my db

*EDIT 2: actual code looks like (sorry, first time working with DateTime):*

**SIGN UP VIEW:**

```
<input type="input" id="antitetanica" name="antitetanica" value="
<?php $date = date_create_from_format( 'm/Y', $antitetanica )->format('m/Y'); ?>" /><br /><br>
```

**EDIT VIEW:**

```
<label for="antitetanica">Data da última dose antitetânica:</label>
<input type="input" name="antitetanica" id="antitetanica" value="<?php $date = new DateTime( $antitetanica ); echo $date->format('m/Y'); ?>" /><br /><br>
```

Comment: why are you using varchar for dates in the first place?

Comment: I just rolled back to the date type, but its not solving the problem for me, heh

Comment: that's because MySQL stores it as YYYY-mm-dd ;-) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Date from database PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066166/displaying-date-from-database-php)

Comment: I don't think you've quite got it for the sign-up view ... why are you providing a value?  Shouldn't it just be: `<input type="input" id="antitetanica" name="antitetanica" value="" /><br /><br>` and leave the PHP for once the form is submitted?

Comment: Then, for the Edit view - why not just: `<input type="input" name="antitetanica" id="antitetanica" value="<?php date_create_from_format( Y-m-d', $antitetanica )->format('m/Y'); ?>" /><br /><br>` (because it's coming from the database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because strtotime doesn't recognise 'antitetanica' ('tetanus') as a valid date:

[PHP strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Even assuming that you've missed a '$' off the start of that string and are actually attempting to feed strtotime a string value which has come from your database - this is not what it is for.  You can't feed it 98/9889 and hope to get a valid date.

**EDIT**

You had the right idea - but `strtotime` was the wrong way to create your date object.

If your input is "03/2013", you need to convert that into a valid date object that PHP can work with.  You do that with [DateTime::createFromFormat();](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm/Y', '03/2013' ); //<< Object-Oriented Style
```

or

```
$date = date_create_from_format( 'm/Y', '03/2013' ); //<< Procedural Style
```

Once you have a date object, you can then output it in whatever format you like:

```
$date->format('m/Y'); //<< Object
```

or

```
date_format( $date, 'm/Y' ); //<< Procedural
```

So - in your original question (storing the date as a string in the database), it would look like:

```
echo date_create_from_format( 'm/Y', $antitetanica )->format('m/Y');
```

But now that you have an actual DATE object in your database, that statement looks something like:

```
echo date_create_from_format( 'Y-m-d', $antitetanica )->format('m/Y');
```

Which is NOT the ideal way to do it ... but I'm painting a picture for you here.

A better way to work with dates now that you have actual DATES in your database, is with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

When you retrieve your data from the database, you can now do something like:

```
$date = new DateTime( $antitetanica ); //<< (where $antitetanica = "2013-03-01")

echo $date->format('m/Y'); //<< "03/2013"
```

**SO - How to get the date from a user in the first place?**

There are several ways you could do this.  You could get the user to enter the date using multiple 'select' form elements, or multiple 'text' form elements, or a single 'text' form element - and each of these ways would need to be handled differently in PHP.

Let's say you decide to have the user enter the date "03/2013" into a single text field.  Over on the server side of things, you'd need to follow exactly the same steps as above - that is:

1. Convert user input to a valid DateTime object
2. Format and insert the date into your database

So:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm/Y', $userInput );

INSERT INTO myTable ( antitetanica ) VALUES ( '$date->format('Y-m-d')' ) //<< Pseudocode
```

As 2 text input fields, that might look like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm/Y', $userMonth . '/' . $userYear );

INSERT INTO myTable ( antitetanica ) VALUES ( '$date->format('Y-m-d')' ) //<< Pseudocode
```

Comment: Hm, got it. Any suggestion of how can i call the date in my database, then? And thanks for explaining about strotime

Comment: First of all, is your description of the value you are storing accurate?  Are you ACTUALLY storing 98/9889?  If so, what is it that you are trying to represent with that?

Comment: I just signed up using 03/2013 and it's showing up as 31/1219. It seems i got 0000-00-00 in my database.

Comment: OK, and you are using the 'date' type for that column in your database now?

Comment: Yes, plus i rolled back my entire code to value="<?php echo $dados['antitetanica'] ?>" and now it shows 00/0000 in the site and 0000-00-00 in the db

Comment: OK - updating my answer ... just a tic :)

Comment: Ok, almost working! What should i do if i do not have a pre-defined input? Like... the person signing up should give me that info and it can be random =P